# xbee.remote_at not working

Tags: python, serial-port, xbee, zigbee

I am using python-xbee to work with XBee modules (Python 2.7). I have an XBee (coordinator) directly connected to my laptop through a serial port and another separate one (endpoint). I can easily communicate with them both using the `at` command, but I can't communicate with them using `remote_at`.

When I run

```
import serial
from xbee.zigbee import ZigBee
import time

PORT = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
BAUD_RATE = 9600

def print_xbee_data(data):
    print(data)

serial_port = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)
# For some reason escaped=True does not work
xbee = ZigBee(serial_port, escaped=True, callback=print_xbee_data)

xbee.send('at', frame='a', command='nd', parameter=None)

# Delay: to wait to keep the thread running to receive the response(s)
time.sleep(5)
```

The output is:

```
{'status': '\x00', 'frame_id': '\x01', 'parameter': {'status': '\x00', 'source_addr': 'a\xd4', 'parent_address': '\x00\x00', 'profile_id': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@0\xbd@', 'device_type': '\x02', 'node_identifier': ' ', 'manufacturer': '\x10\x1e'}, 'command': 'ND', 'id': 'at_response'}
```

But when I run (I am using both escaped and not-escaped address formats just to be sure)

```
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr=b'a\xd4', command='MY')
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr=b'\x61\xd4', command='MY')
xbee.send('remote_at',
          frame_id='A',
          dest_addr_long='\x00\x13\xa2\x00@0\xbd@',
          dest_addr='a\xd4',
          options='\x02',
          command='D0',
          parameter='\x02')
xbee.send('remote_at',
          frame_id='A',
          dest_addr_long='\x00\x13\xa2\x00\x40\x30\xbd\x40',
          dest_addr='\x61\xd4',
          options='\x02',
          command='D0',
          parameter='\x02')

time.sleep(5)
```

I get no output.

- Why doesn't `escaped=True` work?
- Why don't I get any output?
- How can I go about fixing the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remote_at requires a non-zero frame_id to return a response. Run:

```
xbee.remote_at(dest_addr='\x61\xd4', command='MY', frame_id='A')
```

and the output is:

```
{'status': '\x00', 'source_addr': '\x00\x00', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n\x05\xab', 'frame_id': 'A', 'command': 'MY', 'parameter': '\x00\x00', 'id': 'remote_at_response'}
```

Although the status is OK (`'status': '\x00'`) the above command is not doing what we want. Here `'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n\x05\xab'` is the address of local XBee (coordinator). In order for the command to do what we want it to (send `MY` command to the remote device) we MUST specify the 64-bit address (long). Therefore the correct command is:

```
xbee.remote_at(dest_address_long='\x00\x13\xa2\x00@0\xbd@', dest_addr='a\xd4', command='MY', frame_id='A')
```

Replacing `dest_addr='a\xd4'` with `dest_addr='\xff\xfe` works, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. `escaped=True` is only if you have `ATAP` set to 2 (escaped API mode) instead of 1 (API mode).
2. Are you sure your modules are joined to each other, and you're not seeing an `ATND` response from your local device?  Make sure you're using the address of the remote module.

Comment: I don't understand. Both modules are `API` mode (not `AT`). Just to confirm I use XCTU to send commands from the local XBee (coordinator) to read DIO/ADC off the remote one (end point) and it works perfectly. Doesn't that confirm that the modules are joined? If not, can you explain or share a link for further reading? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it works in XCTU shows that they are joined.  I'm not intimately familiar with python-xbee, so I'm limited on what I can recommend there.